# How to get String data from field inside a refrenced document (Firebase)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In my Flutter Application I would like to get some information from a field which contains a refrence to another Collection. I don't know how to get to the information from the field inside the referenced document.

Down below are two pictures of both collections.

The first picture contains the main collection where the field ("geslacht") refers to: "/gender/Girl"

[image: Collection 1]

The second picture shows the referenced collection.

[image: Collection 2]

I currently have written the following piece (following this [tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#0))

```
class Record {
  final String name;
  var color;
  final DocumentReference reference;
  Record.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map, {this.reference})
      : assert(map['name'] != null),
        assert(map['geslacht'] != null),
        name = map['name'],
        color = map['geslacht'];
  Record.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      : this.fromMap(snapshot.data, reference: snapshot.reference);  
  @override
  String toString() => "Record<$name:$votes>";
}
```

Which perfectly gets the data from the field called "name"
and returns a instance of DocumentReference for the field called "geslacht"

I would love to get the information in this referenced document. 
So to conclude the value "pink" is what I am trying a get. (The path would be baby --> dana --> geslacht --> gender --> girl --> color --> pink )

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You will have to `get()` the other document using that DocumentReference, just like you would if you built the DocumentReference yourself.  Cloud Firestore will not automatically follow references for you - you have to write code for that.

Comment: as Android Studio does not have a very easy to use variable explorer, what would the variable color be if I changed the line to color = map[ 'geslacht'].get()?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand your question.  I don't work with Flutter, but the need to get() referenced documents remains the same for all platforms.

Answer (score 1):

You need to query for your data using that reference, you currently only grab that first document:

```
class Record {
  final String name;
  var color;
  final DocumentReference reference;
  Record.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map, {this.reference})
      : assert(map['name'] != null),
        assert(map['geslacht'] != null),
        name = map['name'],
        color = map['geslacht'];
  Record.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      : this.fromMap(snapshot.data, reference: snapshot.reference);  
  @override
  String toString() => "Record<$name:$votes>";
}
```

What you need to do is to perform another query like this:

```
_getGender(ref) async {
  // ref is '/gender/Girl/' in your case
  var query = await Firestore.instance.document(ref).get();
  print('color is: ' + query.data['color'])
}
```

Comment: according to the [documentations](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference) you can get the path (as String) by using getpath() could I pass the result of getpath as attribute for 'ref' ?

Comment: That documentation is for native Android development, I believe there's no `getPath()` method for Flutter Firestore plugin. Nevertheless, just grab that reference you have saved on your "baby" document and use it to perform another query like I described in my answer.